# How to send as image/png a column chart that was created in google-apps-script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

Created a column chart that can be seen in web app, however don't know how to attach it to emails of recipients as png.

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput().setTitle('results');
var imageData = Utilities.base64Encode(chart.getAs('image/png').getBytes());
var image = Utilities.newBlob(chart.getAs("image/png"));
var imageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + encodeURI(imageData);
htmlOutput.append("First part");
htmlOutput.append("<img border=\"1\" src=\"" + imageUrl + "\">");
```

And how to attach logo (have the image of it in Drive), so that it will be on the top-right corner of message body?

Have no idea how to do it

Comment: What is the current issue of your script? And, can you provide your expected result?

Comment: Issue is connected with creating column chart by analizing answers of students from google forms and sending each column chart to each student by gmail.